# Redirect to internal path .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I just want to redirect from

- mydomain.com/foo

to

- mydomain.com/foo/bar

My root .htaccess:

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
  </IfModule>
```

Any simple answer would be pretty appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `RewriteRule ^foo/?$ /foo/bar [R=302,L]` to the rewrites:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^foo/?$ /foo/bar [R=302,L]
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```